# RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, cudnn, cross-entropy

## **Why is there no way to calculate the loss value? (About CrossEntropyLoss)**

My code is a binary classification problem. I try to calculate the loss value in the final test stage, and finally use the loss value to draw a histogram.
However, there will always be errors in the part of calculating the loss value, and there are several times when the data format is different.
Please help, thank you

```
# when batch size (BATCH) is 1
def eval_model_one(model, test_dataloader, order=None):
    # eval_model_one(model, test, [locate])

    test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataloader, shuffle=False, batch_size=1)

    # load well-trained model
    net = model().cuda()
    
    # evaluation mode
    net.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        test_loss = 0
        test_acc = 0
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        
        for i, data in enumerate(test_dataloader, 0):
            img0, label1 = data
            # print(f'label1: ', label1)
            
            # change the order of 12 leads
            # pick specific number of lead
            if order is not None:
                img0 = img0[:, order, :]
            
                # print(f'img0: ', img0)
                # print(f'img0.shape: ', img0[0][0].shape)
                # print(f'orde: ', order)
                
            
            img0, label1 = Variable(img0.cuda()), Variable(label1.cuda().type(torch.cuda.LongTensor))
            img0 = img0.unsqueeze(dim = 1).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
                    
            
            # 計算前向傳播，並且得到損失函數的值
            output1 = net(img0)
            loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            loss1 = loss(output1, label1)

            # 記錄誤差
            test_loss += loss1.item()
            print(f'test_loss: ', test_loss)

            # 計算分類的準確率
            prediction1 = output1.data.max(1)[1]
            accuracy1 = prediction1.eq(label1.data).cpu().sum().numpy()/img0.size(0)*100
            # print(f'accuracy1: ', accuracy1)
            test_acc += accuracy1
            # print(f'test_acc: ', test_acc)

            # test_losses.append(test_loss / len(test_dataloader))
            # test_acces.append(test_acc / len(test_dataloader))

    return (test_loss/len(test_dataloader))

############################################################################################
# plot activation map
# data_all : a list contains tuples including 12 leads, (lead data, age, agegp, gender)
# lead_name : the order of the lead
# locate : the index of lead you used to training the model  ECG 的第幾個 lead
# model : the model
# model_name : the model name
# row_num : the number of the observation  你要用第幾筆資料下去畫
# cut : the number of time steps you want to remove respectivly  您要分別移除的 the number of time steps
# demographic: the paramter of eval_model() from training.py
# multi: the paramter of eval_model() from training.py


def plot_am(data_all, lead_name, locate, model, model_name, row_num, cut, demographic=None, multi=None):

    # data = data_all[row_num]
    # data = data[0]
    # data = np.array(data)
    # data = np.reshape(data, (5000, 12))
    # img = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # img.columns = lead_name

    data = data_all[row_num]
    data = data[0]
    img = pd.DataFrame(data).T
    img.columns = lead_name

    # plot the single lead data
    dpi_value = 300
    plt.figure(figsize=(25, 3))
    signal = img[lead_name[locate]]
    plt.plot(signal, color='black', linewidth=3)
    plt.xlim((0, 5000))
    plt.ylim((-20, 20))
    plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

    # eliminate the margin
    plt.gca().set_axis_off()
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, right=1, left=0, hspace=0, wspace=0)
    plt.margins(0, 0)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())

    plt.savefig("/home/server_605_3090/huanci/ECG_NSAID/plot/one_lead_{}_data_{}.png".format(lead_name[locate], row_num), dpi=dpi_value, bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close()

    # plot activation map
    data = torch.from_numpy(data[0, :])
    data = data.unsqueeze(dim=0).unsqueeze(dim=0).unsqueeze(dim=0)
    data = Variable(data.cuda())
    data = data.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)

    # load model and weight
    net = model().cuda()

    size = (2500, 300)
    layer = []
    for a in ['conv1', "layer1", "layer2", "layer3", "layer4"]:
        target = a
        # grad cam is here!!!!
        grad_cam = GradCam(model=net, target_layer_name=target, use_cuda=True)
        mask, pred = grad_cam(data, size)
        heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(255*mask), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
        heatmap = np.float32(heatmap)/255

        # read the single lead just plotted previously #變成multi-lead了
        # 1 specifies to load a color image
        img = cv2.imread("/home/server_605_3090/huanci/ECG_NSAID/plot/one_lead_{}_data_{}.png".format(lead_name[locate], row_num), 1)
        # resize the figure of single lead data
        img = np.float32(cv2.resize(img, size))/255
        # merge the figure with the heatmape produced by grad cam  將圖形與 grad cam 生成的 heatmape 合併
        img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.6, heatmap, 0.4, 0)
        layer.append(img)


    # plot the importance for each time section
    loss_list = []
    s = cut
    
    for z in range(int(5000/s)):  # ecah sample           
        test = copy.deepcopy(data_all[row_num])
        test[0][:, (z*s):((z+1)*s)] = 0
        test = [test]
        # def eval_model_one(model, test_dataloader, order=None):
        test_loss = eval_model_one(model, test, [locate])
        loss_list = loss_list + [test_loss]*s

    lead_important = pd.DataFrame(np.array([loss_list]).T, columns=['test_loss'])
    # print(lead_important)
    
    y_name = 'test_loss'
    lead_list = list(range(1, 5001, 1))
    score_list = lead_important.loc[:, y_name]

    # re scale the importance
    score_list = score_list - np.min(score_list)
    scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    score_list = scale.fit_transform(np.array(score_list).reshape(-1, 1))  # Data

    plt.figure(figsize=(25, 3))
    plt.bar(lead_list, score_list.squeeze(), width=1, label='lead_list')
    plt.xlim((0, 5000))
    plt.ylim((0, 1))
    plt.gca().set_axis_off()
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, right=1, left=0, hspace=0, wspace=0)
    plt.margins(0, 0)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    plt.savefig('/home/server_605_3090/huanci/ECG_NSAID/plot/lead{}_data{}_step{}.png'.format(lead_name[locate], row_num, s), dpi=dpi_value, bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close()
  

    # read the single lead just plotted previously
    # 1 specifies to load a color image
    img = cv2.imread("/home/server_605_3090/huanci/ECG_NSAID/plot/one_lead_{}_data_{}.png".format(lead_name[locate], row_num), 1)
    # read the bar chart of time step importance just plotted
    # 1 specifies to load a color image
    heatmap = cv2.imread('/home/server_605_3090/huanci/ECG_NSAID/plot/lead{}_data{}_step{}.png'.format(lead_name[locate], row_num, s), 1)
    # resize the plots
    img = np.float32(cv2.resize(img, size))/255
    heatmap = np.float32(cv2.resize(heatmap, size))/255
    img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.6, heatmap, 0.4, 0)
    # the heatmaps of each layer
    img = np.concatenate((layer[0], layer[1], layer[2], layer[3], layer[4], img), axis=0)
    cv2.imwrite("/home/server_605_3090/huanci/ECG_NSAID/plot/{}_lead_{}_data_{}_gradcam.png".format("SCNet_testing", lead_name[locate], row_num), np.uint8(255*img))


# def plot_am(data_all, lead_name, locate, model, model_name, row_num, cut=None, demographic=None, multi=None):
plot_am(data_all=lead, lead_name=lead_name, locate=0, model=model, model_name=model_name, row_num=0, cut=20)
```

About the code pasted above
Successfully calculated the loss value (about CrossEntropyLoss)